# помогите вывести дату по убыванию

Tags: c

Выводится неправильно, в чем моя ошибка?

```
#include"structure.h"
#include"future_time.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int future_time(int *spin, system *library)
{
    int size = 100;
    int data[size];
    for(int i = 0; i<*spin; i++)
    {
        data[size] = library[i].day + library[i].month + library[i].year;
        span_r = library[i].span;
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if(data[size]<data[i]) size = i;
            printf("%d\n", data[size]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите, чтоб выводилось?

Comment: число, которое суммируется из введенного дня, месяца и даты. Но по убыванию.

Comment: Одно число? Или отсортировать массив нужно? Опишите словами, что, по-вашему, делает программа. Да, обычно это не принято, но вы опишите, что делает **каждая строчка**, и **зачем**. Думаю, прояснится многое.

Comment: @Harry В отдельном модуле я ввожу даты(день, месяц, год). Здесь мне нужно добиться того, чтобы эти даты были расположены по убыванию. Но мне не важно в каком виде это будет сделано. Поэтому я тупо складываю день, месяц, и год. Понимаете о чем я? Это мой идиотский эксперимент. Вообще мне нужно отсортировать фильмы по дате, но чтобы в начале стояли новые фильмы, т.е. у которых дата больше всего. Я уже вторые сутки не могу понять как это отсортировать именно в моем случае. Я знаю про метод пузырьком, но у меня не получается.

Comment: @Harry Если бы вы мне помогли с конечной целью, то я бы был вам по уши признателен...

Comment: Вам нужно написать именно свою сортировку? Стандартная функция `qsort` не годится?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрим, что же вы тут делаете...

```
span_r = library[i].span;         // Эта строка роли не играет, выбрасываем
```

Так, в первых же строках

```
for(int i = 0; i<*spin; i++)
{
    data[size] = library[i].day + library[i].month + library[i].year;
```

вы выскакиваете за пределы массива, потому как изначально `size` равно размеру массива...

Дальше можно и не смотреть, но...

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(data[size] < data[i])
        size = i;
```

Т.е. после первого `data[size] < data[i]` вы хотите завершения цикла, так? Кстати, конечно, во вложенном цикле можно индексной переменной дать то же имя, что и во внешнем, но вы точно знаете, что делаете?..

А пока `data[size] >= data[i]`, вы многократно выводите `data[size]`?

Вы, конечно, извините, но ваш код - полный бред, даже не учитывая того, что нам неизвестно, что у вас за тип `system` и т.п.

Если вы хотите четкого ответа - вам надо по крайней мере ясно поставить задачу - для самого себя для начала. Понять из вашего кода, что вы хотите, невозможно.